# SharePoint Designer 2013 creating InfoPath Forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list-form

I have created a Workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013 for a Site in SharePoint Online. The Workflow gathers requirements from a User using the 'Collect' instruction.

As the Workflow has been created SPD has created forms to use in the Workflow.

However, these are Infopath Forms, not .apsx pages

When I try to use these forms on my SharePoint Online Site, the Browsers are incompatible with infopath and I cannot update the forms.

I don't want Infopath forms as they are being deprecated in the future. So my question is how can I get SPD2013 to create .aspx form, not Infopath.

Thanks as always,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You cannot via SharePoint Designer use ASP.NET forms. There could be a way for you to export your workflow towards Visual Studio (the more recent the better) and have it your way.

However, given that you are trying to publish it on Office 365, may i actually suggest you reconsider your solution (e.g building a Visual Studio package means most likely at least a Sandbox solution (no longer supported and definitely not recommended), towards maybe Microsoft Flow or even more (if your IT strategy allows it) to consider Azure Logic Apps. Both Microsoft Flow and Azure Logic Apps make good use of Azure Functions as extensibility points.

Comment: Hi Marius - thanks for your reply. Are you saying that I have to use InfoPath forms if I create the Workflow in SPD ? 
The original workflow is in SharePoint 2010 and used .aspx forms. When I rewrote it for SharePoint Online I expected it to do the same but it's given me InfoPath forms which are being deprecated. This feels wrong, like SPD has picked the wrong technology to implement.

Or do I have a massive gap in my knowledge here ?

Comment: Also, further testing has revealed the Infopath forms incompatible with all browsers other than IE which makes the workflow essentially useless. Infopath cannot be the answer from what I am seeing.

Comment: I'm saying that SPD is definitely end of road and that remains particularly true when dealing with SP-O, though still supported until 2020+. InfoPath's future is also cloudy, with PowerApps picking up lately influence.